# Insert from select in laravel using eloquent

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

I am using laravel 8. I want to insert multiple rows by selecting from one table to another.  I am using DB::statement() but now want to do it using eloquent. Here is my sample code:

```
DB::statement("insert into bank_information (user_id, bank_id, account_name,account_number)
        select applicant_id,bank_id,account_name,account_number from applicant_bank_information
        where erec_applicant_bank_information.applicant_id =".$applicant_id);
```

How can I do it using single eloquent command ? Also, Is there any other smarter/faster way for it in laravel ??

Answer (score 5):

I do not know of a Eloquent way for this, but after Laravel 5.7.17 we have a new method in the query builder insertUsing(). Unfortunately this is not mentioned in the official documentation.

The query builder code will be something like this:

```
$select = DB::table('applicant_bank_information as abi')
    ->select('applicant_id','bank_id','account_name','account_number')
    ->where('abi.applicant_id', $applicant_id);
    
$rows_inserted = DB::table('bank_information')
    ->insertUsing(['user_id','bank_id', 'account_name','account_number'], $select);
```

Tested and working. Keep in mind that you do not run the select request with ->get().